# Input type="range". Значение value всегда равно нулю

Tags: jquery, input, rangeslider

Хочу использовать Input type="range" для горизонтальной прокрутки блока. Но в процессе столкнулся с проблемой - всегдf возвращается значение value равное нулю.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

```js
var $input = $('input'),
    $scroll = $input.attr('value');
function scrolling() {
  $input.on('input', function () {
    console.log('value: ' + $scroll);
  }); 
}
scrolling();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="changer" type="range" min="0" max="1000" step="1" value="0"/>
```

Comment: Как бы написал [Алексей Шиманский](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482) - Асинхронщина. Сначало создаётся $scroll, а потом он же и выводится, где его значение равно 0

Comment: Может я что-то упустил, так как не пользуюсь фреймворками, но часто вижу пишут переменные со знаком `$`. Зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначало переменная `scroll` получает значение, затем вызывается функция `scrolling`, где при изменении слайдера в консоль выводится всё таже выше назначенная `scroll`

Вместо объявления переменной, можно написать функцию получения её

```
$scroll = function() { return $input.val(); }
console.log('value: ' + $scroll());
```

Или вовсе обойтись без jquery

```js
function change(e) { console.log(e.value); }
```

```html
<input type='range' min='0' max='1000' step='1' value='0' oninput='change(this)'>
```